# Why would I be getting a "no module type" error with django-paypal?

Tags: python, django, django-paypal

I get the error below on my django view when trying to use the ipn of django-paypal, anyone know why? Or an alternative to executing the ipn situation?

```
 No module named standard.models
```

I did this part:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #...
  'paypal.standard.ipn',
   #...
    ]
```

As well as this:

```
  from paypal.standard.models import ST_PP_COMPLETED
  from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import valid_ipn_received
```

Both of them are from the tutorial yet I get that error, any idea why?

Comment: did you install `django-paypal` correctly? Try `pip install django-paypal` again.

Comment: I'm not absolutely certain, but I believe you need to include `'paypal.standard'` in your INSTALLED_APPS, along with `'paypal.standard.ipn'`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: Anyone find what was that? i am getting the same error right now.

Comment: I have same issue, i understand that i am using 'paypal.standart.ipn' instead of 'paypal.standard.ipn' please check one more time maybe its misspelling like me

Answer (score 0):

One of your files in your project is also called 'paypal' - rename it and then delete the 'paypal.pyc' file if there is one. This fixed it for me.

Comment: Your answer is just a mere guess of the user problem. Your help fits better as a comment.